# ActiveRecordBase.FindAll() does not allow first level cache?

Tags: nhibernate, caching, castle-activerecord, findall, isession

NHibernate's first level cache is available when one use same session. [`ActiveRecordBase.FindAll()`](https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.ActiveRecord/blob/master/src/Castle.ActiveRecord/Framework/ActiveRecordBase.cs) each time creates a new `ISession`. So such a following can not profit from first level cache:

```
void test1()
{
  Car.FindAll();
  Car.FindAll();
  Car.FindAll();
}
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling several `FindAll()` does not force several different sessions. They all use a same session. The reason that `FindAll()` can not benefit is that it internally uses `ICriteria` and `ICriteria` itself can not use first level cache. First level cache is available just for `Load` and `Get`.

More info available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919636/can-first-level-cache-be-used-with-icriteria-or-other-apis).

Answer (score 0):

Not as long as you only use a first level cache (session-based). 
You can, if you enable the second level cache.

See here for information about the liveness of first and second level caches. http://web.archive.org/web/20110514214657/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/11/09/first-and-second-level-caching-in-nhibernate.aspx